# I wonder whether the past tense is interchanged with the present tense

Tags: tenses

The reason I stopped smoking **was** that all my friends had already stopped smoking.

The reason I stopped smoking **is** that all my friends had already stopped smoking.

-

I wonder if the verb "was" is replaced for "is", which reflects the present time. I think it's not possible because the time I stopped smoking was the past, and the cause inspiring the determination to stop smoking was also the past thing.

Is it right?

Answer (score 2):

It's fine either way.  That **was** the reason when the speaker quit smoking, and it still **is** the reason now.  You can't change the reason you did something retroactively, so the tense doesn't change the truth value of the sentence.

Comment: That said, the combination of Simple Present and Past Perfect is rather unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder if the verb "was" is replaced for "is", which reflects the present time.

I'd be more concerned about this one :-)

Surely it looks more understandable and correct to me as:

*I wonder **what would happen** if the verb "was" **were** replaced for "is", which reflects the present time.*

But that's just me.

Comment: Why are you more concerned about that sentence? Are there errors in there?

Comment: @anotherworld Updated.

Comment: I got it! I agree with you. Thanks for correcting it. : )